# Why my domain doesn't map to the server address?

Tags: dns, webserver, domain, nslookup

I have installed DNS server and network manager on my remote server as by following this instruction: https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-bind-server-centos-8-rhel-8/ as below:

var/named/fwd.sssss.com.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sssss.com. root.sssss.com. (
                                              1490        ;Serial
                                              3600        ;Refresh
                                              1800        ;Retry
                                              604800      ;Expire
                                              86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sssss.com.
@       IN  NS      ns2.sssss.com.



;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       94.130.98.33
ns2       IN  A       94.130.98.33
sssss.com.       IN  MX   10    mail.sssss.com.

;A - Record HostName To Ip Address
sssss.com.     IN  A       94.130.98.33
www             IN  A       94.130.98.33
mail            IN  A       94.130.98.33
@               IN  A       94.130.98.33

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sssss.com.
```

var/named/sssss.com.rev:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sssss.com. root.sssss.com. (
                                       1490        ;Serial
                                       3600        ;Refresh
                                       1800        ;Retry
                                       604800      ;Expire
                                       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS          ns1.sssss.com.
@       IN  NS          ns2.sssss.com.
ns1     IN  A           94.130.98.33
ns2     IN  A           94.130.98.33


;Reverse lookup for Name Server
33      IN  PTR         ns1.sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         ns2.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         ns1.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         ns2.sssss.com.

;PTR Record IP address to HostName
33      IN  PTR         www.sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         mail.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         www.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         mail.sssss.com.
```

etc/named.conf:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        //listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        //listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 94.130.98.33; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; 94.130.98.33; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
//forward zone
zone "sssss.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "fwd.sssss.com.db";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};

//backward zone
zone "98.130.94.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "sssss.com.rev";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3:

```
# Generated by parse-kickstart
TYPE="Ethernet"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
UUID="467a30cc-f47a-4c63-a335-f8afab26f559"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR0="94.130.98.33"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT="no"
DNS=94.130.98.33
```

etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search sssss.com
nameserver 94.130.98.33
```

Nginx works on my server address: 94.130.98.33 but my domain doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make this accessible from the internet, you need to update the DNS records at your domain registar. They're currently not set up to use the `k111cne.com` name server. These are the DNS records that are currently configured:

- https://www.nslookup.io/dns-records/sssss.com/cloudflare/
- https://www.nslookup.io/dns-records/www.sssss.com/cloudflare/

Comment: DNS records are OK on domain register.